# docker container runs from Dockerfile but not from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc libc-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "proxy-scraper-checker/main.py" ]
```

And the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    proxy-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: proxy-app
        environment:
           - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

If I run the Dockerfile manually through the docker cmd in the following way:

```
C:\Projects\myprojects\docker-example>docker build --tag my_app .
C:\Projects\myprojects\docker-example>docker run --rm -it my_app
```

Everything seems to work fine and I get the application output logs that it is actually executing:

```
2020-05-30 13:38:53,454 - Thread-1 - INFO - Starting scheduler...
2020-05-30 13:38:55,457 - Thread-1 - INFO - Running job Every 2 seconds do run_pldown_job(<uvloop.Loop running=False closed=False debug=False>) (last run: [never], next run: 2020-05-30 13:38:55)
2020-05-30 13:38:55,457 - Thread-1 - INFO - Pldown Job starting...
80.187.140.26:8080 HTTPS Server/OS Error:
80.187.140.26:80 HTTP Server/OS Error:
146.148.59.22:80 HTTPS Server/OS Error:
89.216.39.217:4145 Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
185.49.93.102:4145 Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
80.240.250.222:4145 Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
185.123.2.170:1080 Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

However, when I try to execute my application through docker-compose in the following way:

```
C:\Projects\myprojects\docker-example>docker-compose up
```

My application seems to start up fine, but then it doesn't continue execution. Below is the output:

```
Creating proxy-app ... done
Attaching to proxy-app
proxy-app    | 2020-05-30 13:28:02,638 - Thread-1 - INFO - Starting scheduler...
```

I tried executing the show logs command:

```
C:\Projects\myprojects\docker-example>docker logs proxy-app
```

But the only log I got was the first line being:

```
2020-05-30 13:28:02,638 - Thread-1 - INFO - Starting scheduler...
```

Any suggestions?

### Update:

I tried building the image through docker using:

```
docker build --tag my_app .
```

And I used this image in the compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    proxy-app:
        image: my_app
```

And it actually works like this.

However, the question still stands, why it doesn't work when I do it this way:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    proxy-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: proxy-app
```

Comment: What does your service look like in the compose file?

Comment: If you want to check the compose file, it is there in my question

Comment: apologies I missed that part - bare with me.

Comment: Thats a tricky one - what if you build the image outs the compose script, then execute the compose script from that image? I do suspect the connection closed error is still in play, but not showing in the logs when built this way

Comment: Just out of sheer curiosity, how come you are running the docker image with the -it flag? Does it run without it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, yes it works even without -it

@james would you be kind enough to guide me on this since I'm a bit new to docker

Comment: build the image like you did before 'docker build --tag my_app .' and then in the compose file remove the build settings and just include the image name - so the compose will use the same image that has already being built in this case

Comment: I say this because I'm not sure the fact you're using compose is the issue - I think the connection closed error is the root of this issues, im trying to prove it some how (its not possible for me to replicate this)

Comment: So apparently if I remove the build settings, docker-compose complains that there is no build context provided.

Also, if you're suspecting that those errors have to do with the application hanging in docker-compose, why wouldn't the error message be displayed?

Comment: Ok so, I managed to build the image the way you told me to, and referenced that built image from docker-compose and it's working fine this way... I can see the same output as executing it directory from the Dockerfile... strange. I am still unsure why it's not working from the docker-compose with my build settings

Comment: Could you provide a folder tree representation of your project? Like: where are the `docker-compose.yml` and the `Dockerfile` located? Also, where are your `python` located?

Comment: Lastly, to see if a container runs, logs are not relevant alone, what you should see first if the output of `docker ps -a` to see if the container didn't exit

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I posted the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I had to add a volume in my docker-compose file for my python application, so that any changes I made there, would be actually reflected when I build from docker-compose.

So my new docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=proxydb
          - POSTGRES_USER=danny
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    proxy-app:
        build: .
        container_name: proxy-app
        volumes:
            - ./src:/src
```

Comment: compose up builds the image the first time it is launched. After that it reuses the image until you rebuild it. Since building takes a lot longer than just bringing it up, I would suggest that you mount a volume from the directory where you have your code in your machine to the app directory in the image. That way as you make changes to your code, your container reflects the changes immediately which speeds up development. Good luck

Comment: I arranged my answer